# Testing rest service

Tags: java, unit-testing, rest, testing, tdd

I'm newbie in TDD, and now I'm trying to test rest service. What I need is somehow to test if the request to the server is sent right as it should be and looks good. Can you provide me any links or suggestions on how to achieve this.

Also: if you can suggest any good book for reading on TDD topic - you are welcome!

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that this might not be the answer you're looking for, but I if you're interested in writing unit tests, then you should focus on testing your units, not their interactions. Unless you are writing the REST client yourself, you don't have any business testing it. If you ARE writing your own implementation of a REST client, you should ask yourself why.

With that in mind, here's how I'd approach the subject: if your client takes an object, just verify that the object has the right values (compare it to an expected result). If your client takes a URL in some form or another, compare THAT with an expected result. Leave testing the actual client to Oracle. It's their job, and you can't fix any errors you may find, Anyway.

Of course, for integration tests, just run the client against the service (or a mock), and compare the response to the expected one.

Answer (score 2):

For adhoc manual testing the Chrome rest client is awesome as suggested by Chris. For automated testing I recommend [rest-assured](http://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/).

If using chrome, I also recommend the below two extensions

1. [JSON Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc)
2. [XML Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eeocglpgjdpaefaedpblffpeebgmgddk)

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Chrome rest client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) and the equivalent [Firefox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) version.

It lets you put in your auth headers and see the return code as well as parsing json for you.